# Why this Integer comparison gives equal references?

Tags: java

I that know in Java the == operator compares references, not the values pointed to, but if so why this gives equal comparison?:

```
class MainClass{      
   public static void main(String[] args) {      
      Integer x = 2;
      Integer y = 2;
      if(x==y) System.out.println("Equal");
   }
}
```

Comment: Integers in a certain range are cached for performance.

Comment: @Glains There is any way to avoid that? I'm trying to tranverse a Queue<Integer> by doing poll() and adding back with add(), and need to check when I arrive to the original top of the Queue<Integer> again.

Comment: @gian_ Use `new Integer(2)`.

Comment: You can disable the cache, but you have to configure the JVM, which i do not recommend for this type of problem.